# How to make clickable dates work in FullCalendar using Angular?

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I started using FullCalendar-Angular and I'm stuck. I cannot make the clickable 
dates  to work or I haven't understand correctly. Do I have to make any other actions other than set `[navLinks]="true"` in my `fullcalendar` component? If yes what should I do?

My code:

```
<full-calendar defaultView="dayGridMonth" 
              [plugins]="calendarPlugins"
              [aspectRatio]="2.2"
              [navLinks]="true"
              [header]="{ left: 'prevYear,prev,next,nextYear today',
                          center: 'title',
                          right: ' dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'}">
</full-calendar>
```

Comment: where is your (dateClick)="handleDateClick($event)" .    Create a StackBlitz if this doesn't help

Comment: Using navLinks in the Angular plugin seems to cause a script error: `Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined` - demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-rehxng?file=src/app/app.component.html . But it works fine in regular fullCalendar. I would suggest raising a bug with the maintainers. See https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs for instructions

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need two more things on top of your solution

```
(dateClick)="handleDateClick($event)"

[events]="calendarEvents"
```

In your component

```
calendarEvents: EventInput[] = [
    { title: 'Event Now', start: new Date() }
];

handleDateClick(arg) {
    if (confirm('Would you like to add an event to ' + arg.dateStr + ' ?')) {
      this.calendarEvents = this.calendarEvents.concat({ // add new event data. must create new array
        title: 'New Event',
        start: arg.date,
        allDay: arg.allDay
      })
    }
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/github/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-example-projects/tree/master/angular?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: yeah, I thought of doing these steps but I read this in their docs `When true, day headings and weekNumbers will become clickable. When clicked, these links will bring the user to a view that represents the day/week.` and this https://fullcalendar.io/docs/navLinks-demo and I assumed that it doesn't need functions to work @prabhatojha